# How to counter olaf top?

Tags: league-of-legends

How do you counter olaf top? It is so hard he always kills be at lvl 2 or 3. I have tried vlad but no good he still can get in range super easily.

Answer (score 2):

A common type of top laner is *sustain-based*. They tipically have some healing form or life steal or shield (think udyr, warwick, nasus, irelia,..), which they abuse by buying a lot of armor (or magic resist) depending of which type of damage their enemy deals the most. This amplifies the effect of healing (if my armor blocks half your damage then you can think of my heals as being double as strong, since you need twice as many hits to compensate my healing) and make them win their lanes by sheer attrition (hit the enemy some, heal up, hit him some, heal up, and repeat).

Olaf counters this by having a true damage skill on a low cooldown, which makes it difficult to outsustain him.

So apart from ganking him early on, the type of champions that beat olaf are those that are more *duel based*, like riven or rumble, where they have so much damage up close that if olaf tries to harass you, you fight him back and **don't let him heal back up**.

If you want to play vlad against him, buy boots as first item and try movement speed quints; avoid his axes and you should be able to do free damage to him all the time. 
Also you might not want to have a CC based team since his ultimate negates all that.

Good luck

TL;DR: Olaf beats sustain top laners. Pick duelist or someone that can outrange/kite him.

Answer (score 0):

To make it short and simple: **Warwick** can out sustain Olaf, and **Yorick** can use his range to punish Olaf.

Answer (score 0):

Olaf is pretty weak against champions that can poke from range like kennen, kennen can farm well and poke at the same time, combined with a WOTA he can shrug off harass that olaf gives him.
Yorick can out sustain olaf by a long shot, he has a nice chase, sustain and a nice ult which can prevent ganks and even come out on top.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use sites like http://www.picklol.net/olaf to find the best counter-pick to certain heroes.

I tried Yorick, as suggested by the link, and I simply won my lane.